# What data is written out when a higher precision is used to display a number than the one supported by the format?

Tags: c++, floating-point

[The IEEE 754 double precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a binary precision of 53 bits, which translates into log10(2^53) ~ 16 significant decimal digits.

If the double precision format is used to store a floating point number in a 64 bit-long word in the memory, with 52 bits for the significand and 1 hidden bit, *but a larger precision is used to output the number* to the screen, what data is actually read from the memory and written to the output?

How can it even be read, when the total length of the word is 64 bit, does the read-from-memory operation on the machine just simply read more bits and interprets them as an addition to the significand of the number?

For example, take the number 0.1. It does not have an exact binary floating point representation regardless of the precision used, because it has an indefinitely repeating binary floating point pattern in the significand.

If 0.1 is stored with the double precision, and printed to the screen with the precision >16 like this in the C++ language:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 0.1; 
    cout << setprecision(50) << "x= " << x << endl;
};
```

The output (on my machine at the point of execution), is:

> x = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541

If the correct rounding is used with 2 guard bits and 1 sticky bits, can I trust the decimal values given by the first three non-zero binary floating point digits in the error 5.551115123125783e-17?

Comment: This will be highly dependent on programming language / operating system / system libraries. Are you asking specifically about C++? If so, it's probably worth adding the relevant tag. (But even then, the language spec doesn't specify exactly what should be output here.)

Comment: Yes, I am mainly interested in C++. So, what is read after the (p - 1) digit depends on the programming language? What if I have two numbers that are stored consecutively in the memory and I continue reading the first number beyond (p-1), will the beginning of the next number be read?

Comment: No: what's read from memory will always be the 64 bits (8 bytes) of the double-precision value. It's what happens next that'll be language- and system-dependent: the details of converting an IEEE 754 binary64 value to a decimal output string are messy, and there are tradeoffs between accuracy, speed, and ease of implementation. Not to mention that some mainstream languages (C, C++, Python) don't make any assumptions about floating-point format being IEEE 754 in the first place.

Comment: OK, so if the conversion to string is language dependent, it is best to treat everything after the (p-1)th digit as garbage, right?

Comment: Perhaps. It depends on your needs. E.g., if you're writing those binary64 values out to a text file in decimal, in the hope of reading them back later and getting the exact same values you started with, you'll need to write 17 significant digits to be sure of recovering the original values. (And you'll also need some guarantees from the implementation - ideally guarantees about correct rounding, but weaker guarantees could be enough.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every binary fraction is exactly equal to some decimal fraction. If, as is usually the case, `double` is a binary floating point type, each `double` number has an exactly equal decimal representation.

For what follows, I am assuming your system uses IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point to represent `double`. That is not required by the standard, but is very common. The closest number to `0.1` in that format has exact value 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

Although this number has a lot of digits, it is exactly equal to 3602879701896397/2<sup>55</sup>.  Multiplying both numerator and denominator by 5<sup>55</sup> converts it to a decimal fraction, while increasing the number of digits in the numerator.

One common approach, consistent with the result in the question, is to use round-to-nearest to the number of digits required by the format. That will indeed give useful information about the rounding error on conversion of a string to `double`.

Comment: "the closest number to 0.1 in that format has exact value" : Two questions. 1. How can this value be exact, when the double precision format IEEE 754 only has 52 bit long significand, which means that the the decimal place values after the 16th digit in that number are not represented by the format at all? 2. The closest number to 0.1 is already a result of a rounding operation that was performed on 0.1, in the round-to-nearest mode, so it is not exact.

Comment: @tmaric: That value _is_ exact, and while in decimal it takes 55 significant digits to represent exactly, that's not inconsistent with it only needing 53 significant bits (and therefore being compatible with IEEE 754 binary64). For a smaller example, consider that 3/16 only requires two significant bits to represent in binary floating-point, but in decimal it's `0.1875`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: hm, 0.1 in decimal takes 2 decimal floating point digits (p=2) to be exactly represented, and in binary, it cannot be represented exactly at all, irrespective of the length of the significant, just like 0.333333333333... cannot be represented exactly in the decimal system.

Comment: Or do you guys mean that the number rounded to is a floating point number and therefore exactly represented by the format, and not 0.1?

Comment: @tmaric: Yep. None of that is inconsistent with the statement that the value `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` can be represented exactly in IEEE 754 binary64 format.

Comment: One more question: if the rounded number is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` and it is represented exactly, it is represented exactly up to the precision given by the format. What I mean is that if you say that what comes after the (p-1)th place in the string of this number is language dependent, even if the rounded number is exactly represented by the standard, part of the string will surely be garbage?

Comment: @tmaric I don't think the standard says anything about the exact output you'll get, it's compiler dependent. But the process of producing an exact output is a well known problem that I expect any compiler to get right. None of the string will be garbage.

Comment: @MarkRansom: If -log10(2**-52) gives me 16 decimal digits that can be exactly represented by the IEEE double format, I still have trouble understanding, how can I  store exactly a number like the one in the string with 50 decimal digits with only 52 binary bits at my disposal. I would need a binary floating point format that has a 167 binary digit long significand to exactly represent a decimal number with up to -log10(2^-167) ~ 50 decimal digits.

Comment: @tmaric the string is being built in a piece-wise fashion, at no point are the limits of IEEE arithmetic exceeded. I'm sorry I don't have a reference to give you.